# Spring server is not responding to a GET request

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-web

I want to create a Spring service that would return a text upon a GET request at `http://localhost/version`.

For this purpose, I wrote [this code](https://github.com/dpisarenko/spring-server):

[Controller](https://github.com/dpisarenko/spring-server/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/test/VersionController.kt)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/version")
class VersionController {
  @RequestMapping(method=arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
  fun version():String {
      return "1.0"
  }
}
```

[Security configuration](https://github.com/dpisarenko/spring-server/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/test/SecurityConfiguration.kt)

```
@Configuration
open class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
  override fun configure(http:HttpSecurity) {
   http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/version").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository
                        .withHttpOnlyFalse());
  }
}
```

[App](https://github.com/dpisarenko/spring-server/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/test/App.kt)

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class App {
  fun run() {
      SpringApplication.run(App::class.java)
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  App().run()
}
```

When I compile (`mvn compile`), run (`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.AppKt`), and try to access `http://localhost:8080/version`) I get the 404 response.

Why? What part of the code do I need to change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code started to work, after I added the `@RestController` annotation to `VersionController`.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using "(method=arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))"?
try using "(method=RequestMethod.GET)" and it should work.
ot you can use @GET annotation on method itself

Comment: I got compiler errors when I used `(method=RequestMethod.GET)`.